# Handing 32-bit ifindex inside of snmp

Tags: format, snmp, 32-bit, packet

In developing my own SNMP poller, I've come across the problem of being able to poll devices with 32-bit interface indexes.  I can't find anything out there explaining how to covert the hex (5 bytes) into the 32 bit integer or from the integer into hex as it doesn't use simple hex conversion.  Example, the interface index is 436219904.  While doing a pcap with a snmpget, I see the hex for this is 81 d0 80 e0 00 which makes no sense.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how that converts to an integer value.  I've tried to find a RFC dealing with this and have had no luck.  The 16 bit interface values convert as they should.  0001 = 1 and so on.  Only the 32-bit ones seem to be giving me this problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the key piece of info missing from your question is that the ifIndex value in question as used in your polling is an index for the table polled (not mentioned which, but we could assume ifTable), which means it will be encoded in as a subidentifier of the OID being polled (give me [some property] for [this ifIndex]) versus a requested value (give me [the ifIndex] for [some other row of some other table]).

Per [X.209](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.209) (the version of the ASN.1 Basic Encoding Rules used by SNMP) subidentifiers in OIDs (other than the first two) are encoded in one or more octets (8 bits) with the highest order bit used as a continuation bit (i.e. "next octet is part of this subidentifier too"), and then remaining 7 bits for the actual value.

In other words, in your value "81 d0 80 e0 00", the highest bit is set in each of the first 4 octets and cleared in the last octet: this is how you know there are 5 octets in the subidentifier. The remaining 7 bits of each of those octets are concatenated to arrive at the integer value.

The converse of course is that to encode an integer value into a subidentifier of an OID, you have to build it 7 bits at a time.

Answer (score 0):

SNMP uses ASN.1 syntax to encode data. Thus, you need to learn the BER rules,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690

For your case, I can say you watched the wrong data, as if 436219904 is going to be encoded as `Integer32` in SNMP, the bytes should be `1A 00 30 00`.

I guess you have missed some details in the analysis, so you might want to do it once again and add more descriptions (screenshot and so on) to enrich your question.